# Sending Multipart file and @RequestBody in single request

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, file-upload, multipartform-data

In the React web app I'm developing,there is a file upload part with some user data.However, when I'm trying to upload files, server throws the following error.

> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the
>   request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found

**React side**

```
function fileChangedHandler(event) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", event.target.files[0]);
    formData.append("name", event.target.files[0].name);

    SENDER.post(
      "/api/task_resources",{ 
        addedBy: parseInt(localStorage.getItem('id')),
        taskId: parseInt(props.taskId)
      },{
          params: {
            file: formData
        }
        }         
    )
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200) {
          alert("upload suc");
          window.location.reload()
        }
      })
      .catch(err => alert("err"));
  }
```

My **Spring Boot controller** is as follows.

```
@PostMapping("/task_resources")
  public void addResourceToTask(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,@RequestBody AddTaskResourceRequest addResReq) {
      String fileName = fileService.storeFile(file);

      String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
               .path("/api/downloadFile/")
               .path(fileName)
               .toUriString();

       UploadFileResponse response =  new UploadFileResponse(fileName, fileDownloadUri,
              file.getContentType(), file.getSize());

       taskResourceService.addResource(addResReq, fileDownloadUri);
  }
```

Comment: these errors are usually related to `content-type` headers. so check that you are sending correct from the client

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the request using multipart/form-data if your server is especting that. Here is my example implemented using Axios.

```
const postGalleryImageRequest = async (sessionToken, userLogged, image) => {

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('newImage', image);

    const result = await api.post('business/' + userLogged.businessId + '/gallery', data, {
        headers: { 
            Authorization: sessionToken,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
    })  .then((response) => {
            return response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
            ....
        })
    return result;
}
```